# Función javascript no funciona luego de una respuesta AJAX

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

Uso el plugin [Flip](https://nnattawat.github.io/flip/) para crear un div en PHP por cada registro MySQL y hago la llamada vía AJAX, en la cara frontal muestro el nombre y en la cara trasera muestro la información del mismo. Este es mi código:

```
<div class="result"></div>
<script>
   $.post("result.php",{

   }).done(function(resp){
   $(".result").html(resp);
   });

   $(".fff").flip({
    trigger: 'manual'
   });

   function flip_back(idx){
     $(".card_"+idx).flip(true);
   }

   function flip_front(idx){
    $(".card_"+idx).flip(false);
   } 
</script>
```

**result.php**

```
<?php
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM users";
  $res = mysql_query($sql);

  $html='';

  if(mysql_num_rows($res)>0){
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res){
      $id= $row['id'];

      $html.='<div class="card_'.$id.' fff"> 
       <div class="front">'.$row['nombre'].'
       <button onclick="flip_back(\''.$id.'\');">VER INFO</button>            
       </div> 
       <div class="back">'.$row['correo'].'Back content
       <button onclick="flip_front(\''.$id.'\');">VER INFO</button>
       </div></div>';

    }
   echo $html;
  }

?>
```

Lo que quiero es que cada div gire al hacerle click a su botón correspondiente pero la función **onclick** no está funcionando, incluso he puesto las funciones dentro de la respuesta de AJAX y sigue sin funcionar.

¿Cómo puedo resolverlo?

Agradeceré su respuesta.

Answer (score 0):

necesitas agregar la etiqueta de escript en tu callback por ejemplo:

```
<?php
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM users";
  $res = mysql_query($sql);

  $html='';

  if(mysql_num_rows($res)>0){
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res){
      $id= $row['id'];

      $html.='<div id="card_'.$id.' fff"> 
       <div class="front">'.$row['nombre'].'
       <button onclick="flip_back(\''.$id.'\');">VER INFO</button>            
       </div> 
       <div class="back">'.$row['correo'].'Back content
       <button onclick="flip_front(\''.$id.'\');">VER INFO</button>
       </div></div>';

    }
   echo $html;
  }

?>

<script src="tu_archivo.js"> </script> //aqui haces el script que quieres
```

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, ya lo he intentando y tampoco funciona